# How to detect if date changes in select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following SQL query to select rows from through an inner join sorted by the *date*.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      clubnights 
INNER     JOIN club ON clubnights.club = club.club_ID 
WHERE     visibility = 0
AND       date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY  clubnights.date ASC
```

I then load all the data in my HTML via a PHP while loop.

My aim is to echo an HTML header above every section of any given date.

Therefore I am looking to detect (either via PHP or SQL) when a change in date is detected via the select query. Basically, I want to compare the last 'date' column to the current one, and if they do not match I will echo something via PHP.

An example, assuming the following are rows:

```
2016-09-16 - Row 1 // Detect 'change' here as it's the first row

2016-09-16 - Row 2

2016-09-16 - Row 3

2016-09-16 - Row 4

2016-09-16 - Row 5

2016-09-17 - Row 6 // Detect change here as date has changed

2016-09-17 - Row 7

2016-09-17 - Row 8
```

Edit: I am using MySQL

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I am using MySQL. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: How are you ordering within a given date?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: No.  _Within_ a given date what column do you want to use to order the records?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am ordering the records via the date in ascending order. I basically want to add an addition to my PHP that says "If the date changes, echo something". 

Edit: My closest bet would be that I need to check each date with the previous row date, and if they do not match I trigger the PHP echo. However, I'm not too sure how to go around doing this.

Comment: There is _no_ internal order in MySQL.  To make this easier, how are you deriving the row numbers?  Do you have a column for this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I understand correctly, and I do apologies for my lack thereof, I am using the ID column to order the records.

Comment: Not that anyone else cares, but (assuming you fixed the PRIMARY KEY problem) what would the desired result then look like?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirement, then for groups of records sharing the same date, the record with the smallest `club_ID` is the *first* record in that group.  In the answer below, I use a subquery to find the minimum `club_ID` for each date.  This subquery is then joined to your original query to determine which record is the first, for each date.

```
SELECT clubnights.*,
       club.*,
       CASE WHEN t.club_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'change' END AS date_changed
FROM clubnights
INNER JOIN club
    ON clubnights.club = club.club_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(club.club_ID) AS club_ID,
           clubnights.date AS date
    FROM clubnights
    INNER JOIN club
        ON clubnights.club = club.club_ID
    GROUP BY clubnights.date
) t
    ON clubnights.date = t.date AND
       club.club_ID    = t.club_ID
```

Note that I prefer this solution to handling the problem in the PHP presentation layer, because MySQL was designed to manipulate data efficiently, PHP much less so.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    *,
         CASE WHEN @dd!=date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as changed,
         @dd:=date
FROM      clubnights, (select @dd:=null) 
    INNER JOIN club ON clubnights.club = club.club_ID 
WHERE     visibility = 0
AND       date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY  clubnights.date ASC
```

You can define a variable and change it from row to row comparing with current date

Answer (score 2):

well, local variables me be helpful for it. Use the following way!

> When you are displaying data in tables with php loop use the following algorithm

*I am assuming the database is connected.

```
<?php
   $date2 = sortotime("today");
$q = mysql_query("select your_date_column_name as dt from your_table_name");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($q))
{
$date1 = $obj->dt;
if(strtotime($date1) != strtotime($date2))
{ echo "Row Changed"; echo"<br/>"; $date2 = $date1; }

echo $date1;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: mysql_*() functions have been deprecated years ago and were removed as of php v7. Pls do not suggest any solutions using this api.

Comment: Ok. I will take care of it in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can select data from mysql ordered by date ascending, then compare them into php code, Example:

```
$servername = "localhost";  
$username = "username";  
$password = "password";  
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection  
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  
// Check connection  
if ($conn->connect_error) {  
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);  
}   

$sql = "same as your query";  
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
$previousDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1990-01-01');  
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
// output data of each row  
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
 $mysqlDate= date('Y-m-d', $row["date"]);  
   if($previousDate != $mysqlDate)  
    {  
    echo "two different dates";  
    $previousDate = $mysqlDate;  
     }  

   }  
} else {  
echo "0 results";  
}  
$conn->close();
```